# Why iframe font size doesn't change at all?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to change iframe font size into 150%. I already set up in css then the result doesn't change which is still same small text. Why it doesn't change the size?

Here my css codes,

```
#frame{
font-size:150%;
}

.frame {
z-index:2000;
}
```

and then my html code,

```
<div class="frame">
    <iframe id ="frame" srcdoc="<p></p>" width="930"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then a  javascript code that print texts in iframe,

```
document.getElementById("frame").srcdoc += transcript;
```

Comment: Do you have to use an iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function changeSize(){
    var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
    var content = (frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow);
    content.body.style.fontSize = "150%";
}
```

try calling this function after you have added the text to your iFrame like so

```
document.getElementById("frame").srcdoc += transcript;
changeSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS in the parent page won't affect anything inside the iframe. In fact the iframe is almost entirely boxed off from the code on the page where it appears.

Comment: @StudentIT nothing to fix you can't do it if you use iframes ... there are quite a lot of  limitations in using iframes. This is one of them